# Laravel (and not only) Many-to-many relationship Belongs-To-All

Tags: database, laravel, many-to-many, relationships

I have two tables. 'Products' and 'Discounts'.
Then I create a joining table 'discount_product' for Many-to-many relationship. So far so good.

Now if I want a discount to belong to ALL of the products I have to make insertions into the joining table for as many products I have. That means that having 10000+ products I'll have to insert 10000+ rows for one discount into the joining table? And that's only for one discount! What if I have 1000?

That's compelling me into returning to the old (wrong) way of doing it when I just have a column 'product_ids' in the 'Discounts' table with something like this '1|2|4|7|23|...' (or '*' for 'belongs to all') and then make a small piece of PHP code to check if discount belongs to all or to some products. I know it's wrong way of doing it. So is there a better way to make this properly?

Structure:

```
**products**
  id 
  description
  price

**discounts**
  id
  procent
  value

**discount_product**
  product_id
  discount_id
```

Comment: Do you have some code, Controller, Model, Repo, View?

Comment: Not yet, I just migrate a site to Laravel and want to do it proper way. I just think of a concept. But it doesn't matter actually, I will definitely have all Models and Controllers and Migrations for both Products and Discounts, but it will not solve the problem.

Comment: a product can have more then 1 discount?

Comment: Yes, of course. For example there can be personal discounts that will apply to one or many or all products.

Comment: Why many to many? 1 Product has 1 discount, if its 0 or 10 or 20% discount, it has just 1 discount, so just 1 one pivot record. So every product has always 1 "connection" via pivot. If some products, example 100 has to be all 20% discount you have to do this in in your controller and repository. Multiple update. Hope you understand.

Comment: It's not about "used" discounts it's about future discounts. What I want is to be able to create one discount for many people and/or many products, as well as one discount for one client and/or for one product. See in this case I will need many-to-many relationship and specifically belongsToAll method.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to try to change some business logic.

- If the discount is not in the `discount_product` then this means that it applies to all products.
- If the discount is in the `discount_product` then it means that it works only for a certain product.
- If you need to ensure that the discount is not applied to any product, add the field is_active in discounts.

It's just my thoughts.

I believe that sometimes it is useful to denormalize the database because of optimization, and I would do as you suggested with the `product_ids` field.

Comment: Thanx for the comment. I have thought about that before, and in this case we can't use the Laravel's native many-to-many relationship by doing $this->belongsToMany('Product'); It just won't work.... And I know it's very tempting to make it the wrong way :), and I will probably do it if I don't find a better solution...